# C# Sqlite Class table Cant Add Attribute [PrimaryKey]

Tags: c#, sqlite, attributes, primary-key

For Some reason my code does not recognize the attributes.  Like it does in Xamarin when creating a C# SQlite Database class.

```
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace DJipayeEmailer
{

class Company
{
        [PrimaryKey] <----- this attribute says doesnt exist. ( i want to set it as a primary key)
        public int IDCkey  { get; set; }
        public string Company_Name { get; set; }
```

does C# not allow this unless using Xamarin, or am I using the wrong nugget / library?

Comment: i think your confused.... what documentation have you seen regarding that such an attribute exists for that lib, are you not looking for EF core, and then extending it with the EF core sqllite package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace `System.Data.SQLite` in your code is about low-level sql operations, using string based queries. If you want some lite ORM functionality and LINQ queries, you have to install `sqlite-net-pcl` package, attribute you looking for is there.